# How can I make a user list of those who have given feedback on the particular product?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have made a feedback form. Now I want to make a user list of those who have given feedback on the particular product. **My motive is,** that if any user gives feedback on a particular product, he/she won't be able to give another feedback on that particular product and can't see the feedback form. ***A user can share just one feedback on one product.*** But he/she will be able to give feedback on other's products. ***How can I make a user list of those who have given feedback on the particular product?***

***models.py:***

```
class Products(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="merchandise_product_related_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    product_title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length = 250)
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk) + "." + str(self.product_title)


class ProductREVIEWS(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userREVIEW',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='productREVIEWrelatedNAME',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk) + "." + str(self.product) + "(" + str(self.user) + ")"
```

***views.py:***

```
def quick_view(request, quick_view_id):
    quick_view = get_object_or_404(Products, pk=quick_view_id)
    AllProductFeedback = quick_view.productREVIEWrelatedNAME.all()
    TotalProductsFeedback = AllProductFeedback.count()
    OverallFeedback = ProductREVIEWS.objects.all()

    context = {
        "quick_view":quick_view,
        "TotalProductsFeedback":TotalProductsFeedback,
        "AllProductFeedback":AllProductFeedback,
        "OverallFeedback":OverallFeedback,
    }
    return render(request, 'quickVIEW_item.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
User.objects.filter(userREVIEW__product=quick_view)
```

You can however simply let the database prevent creating two `ProductREVIEWS` for the same `user` and `product` combination with a [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint):

```
from django.conf import settings

class ProductReview(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='reviews',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        related_name='reviews',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('user', 'product'),
                name='review_once'
            )
        ]
   
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.pk}.{self.product}({self.user})'
```

with the modified names, it is:

```
User.objects.filter(reviews__product=quick_view)
```

But here the database will thus reject a second review of the same product by the same user.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Product` instead of <s>`Products`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`ProductREVIEWS`</s> to `ProductReview`.

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the manager to fetch the related objects in reverse. Therefore
> normally the `related_name` of a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` is *plural*,
> for example `reviews` instead of <s>`productREVIEWrelatedNAME`</s>.